# How to pause all user embedded youtube videos via jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I have a user embedded youtube video, they've copied and pasted a iframe youtube player into it.

I've looked at a load of questions on stackoverfow and the you tube api but can't seem to figure out how to pause all the videos that are playing on the page from query.

I've tried both of the following but they cause errors cause the player isn't found:

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
    $(this).find('#video-player-flash').pauseVideo();
    $(this).pauseVideo();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `pausePlayer` is a method of HTML5 Video object;

```
// so you need native DOM object
$('iframe').each(function(){
    $(this).find('#video-player-flash').get(0).pause();
    $(this).get(0).pause();
});
```

Comment: This isn't working both lines are just throwing an error about being undefined.

Comment: I aimed to address this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video